Unique homomorphism between free groups
I've been given the following exercise

If $X$ is a set, define $FX$ to be the free group having basis $X$; that is, the elements of $FX$ are reduced words on the alphabet $X$ and multiplication is juxtaposition followed by cancellation. If $\varphi:X\rightarrow Y$ is a function, prove that there is a unique homomorphism $F\varphi:FX\rightarrow FY$ such that $(F\varphi)| X=\varphi$.

I think I have solved the exercise, however I have a few questions marked with $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ below. Here is my attempt:
Let $w\in FX$ be a word. Then $w=\prod_{i\in I} x_i$ is the product of some $x_i\in X$ where repetitions may happen. Define $F\varphi(w)$ as follows: $$(F\varphi)(w)=\prod_{i\in I}\varphi(x_i)$$
$\color{red}{\text{Does } (F\varphi)\mid X\text{ mean } F\varphi\text{ restricted to } X\text{?}}$ I'm confused because I don't think $X$ is a free group, and $F\varphi$ has $FX$ as a domain. Given that they want me to only look at $F\varphi$ with basis-elements as inputs we have $$(F\varphi)(x_i)=\varphi(x_i)$$ I think I can show that $F\varphi$ is unique:
Suppose $(F\varphi)(x)|X=(F\chi)(x)|X$, then $\varphi(x)=\chi(x)$ for all $x\in X$ and so $$\varphi=\chi$$
$\color{red}{\text{Can I assume that another homomorphism must be on the form }F\chi?}$


Your description of $w = \prod_{i\in I} x_i$ where $x_i\in X$ is not quite right - a word is a product of elements of $X$ and their inverses. Also, what is $I$? A word is a finite sequence, and order of multiplication matters, so $I$ had better be a finite ordered set. Better to write $w = \prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{\delta_i}$, where for all $i$, $x_i\in X$ and $\delta_i\in \{1,-1\}$.

Yes, $(F\varphi)\mid X$ means $F\varphi$ restricted to $X$. Here we are identifying $X$ with its image in $FX$ (i.e., identifying an element $x\in X$ with the reduced word $x\in FX$), so that $X\subseteq FX$. Then $(F\varphi)\mid X$ is a function $X\to FY$ (not a group homomorphism, since $X$ is not a group).

"Can I assume that another homomorphism must be on the form $F\chi$?" No, you cannot. You have to prove it! This is the whole point of uniqueness. If $\psi\colon FX\to FY$ is another homomorphism such that $\psi\mid X = \varphi$, then you need to prove that $\psi = F\varphi$. It follows that every homomorphism $\psi\colon FX\to FY$ has the form $\psi = F\chi$ for some $\chi$ (namely $\chi = \psi\mid X$).


